# dns lookup issue on 1.26.7 version kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, dns, containerd

I have built a single control-plane 5 worker nodes cluster using kubeadm and containerd as container runtime. I have deployed a simple debian pod and I am getting flapping results in dns requests.

```
 kubectl get pods -n idfint
NAME                                           READY   STATUS                       RESTARTS         AGE
dnsutils                                       1/1     Running                      1 (32m ago)      148m
```

**nslookup works with flapping results**

```
kubectl -n idfint exec -ti dnsutils -- nslookup kubernetes.default
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

command terminated with exit code 1
❯ kubectl -n idfint exec -ti dnsutils -- nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Name:   kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.96.0.1
```

**resolv.conf**

```
kubectl -n idfint exec -ti dnsutils -- cat /etc/resolv.conf
search idfint.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
nameserver 10.96.0.10
options ndots:5
```

**coredns pods**

```
 kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
coredns-787d4945fb-76shs   1/1     Running   1 (37m ago)   125m
coredns-787d4945fb-cqf6h   1/1     Running   1 (36m ago)   125m
```

**DNS logs**

```
kubectl -n kube-system logs -l k8s-app=kube-dns
[INFO] 192.168.2.224:45158 - 16096 "AAAA IN zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-2.zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-headless.idfint.idfint.svc.cluster.local. udp 108 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 201 0.000281309s
[INFO] 192.168.2.224:45158 - 48889 "A IN zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-2.zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-headless.idfint.idfint.svc.cluster.local. udp 108 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 201 0.000326369s
[INFO] 192.168.94.203:37947 - 5599 "A IN elasticsearch-master-headless. udp 47 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd,ra 122 0.002509108s
[INFO] 192.168.94.203:37947 - 12753 "AAAA IN elasticsearch-master-headless. udp 47 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd,ra 122 0.002659641s
[INFO] 192.168.2.224:50996 - 12767 "AAAA IN zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-1.zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-headless.idfint.idfint.svc.cluster.local. udp 108 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 201 0.00036007s
[INFO] 192.168.2.224:50996 - 45510 "A IN zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-1.zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-headless.idfint.idfint.svc.cluster.local. udp 108 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 201 0.00041101s
[INFO] 192.168.2.224:53782 - 13170 "AAAA IN zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-2.zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-headless.idfint.idfint.svc.cluster.local. udp 108 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 201 0.000294852s
[INFO] 192.168.2.224:53782 - 30072 "A IN zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-2.zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-headless.idfint.idfint.svc.cluster.local. udp 108 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 201 0.000328168s
[INFO] 192.168.2.224:46389 - 44150 "A IN zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-2.zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-headless.idfint.svc.cluster.local. udp 101 false 512" NOERROR qr,aa,rd 200 0.000255174s
[INFO] 192.168.2.224:46389 - 44365 "AAAA IN zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-2.zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-headless.idfint.svc.cluster.local. udp 101 false 512" NOERROR qr,aa,rd 194 0.000391488s
[INFO] 192.168.253.27:51999 - 9019 "A IN zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-headless.idfint.svc.cluster.local. udp 75 false 512" NOERROR qr,aa,rd 294 0.000552174s
[INFO] 192.168.253.27:37983 - 7838 "PTR IN 219.180.168.192.in-addr.arpa. udp 46 false 512" NOERROR qr,aa,rd 277 0.000284047s
[INFO] 192.168.253.27:36526 - 25502 "A IN 192-168-180-219.zookafka00-cp-zookeeper.idfint.svc.cluster.local. udp 82 false 512" NOERROR qr,aa,rd 162 0.000267763s
[INFO] 192.168.253.27:36526 - 50837 "AAAA IN 192-168-180-219.zookafka00-cp-zookeeper.idfint.svc.cluster.local. udp 82 false 512" NOERROR qr,aa,rd 175 0.000349479s
[INFO] 192.168.2.224:60467 - 36863 "AAAA IN zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-1.zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-headless.idfint.svc.cluster.local. udp 101 false 512" NOERROR qr,aa,rd 194 0.000439511s
[INFO] 192.168.2.224:60467 - 33785 "A IN zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-1.zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-headless.idfint.svc.cluster.local. udp 101 false 512" NOERROR qr,aa,rd 200 0.00056036s
[INFO] 192.168.2.224:42488 - 36694 "AAAA IN zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-2.zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-headless.idfint.svc.cluster.local. udp 101 false 512" NOERROR qr,aa,rd 194 0.000322181s
[INFO] 192.168.2.224:42488 - 43356 "A IN zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-2.zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-headless.idfint.svc.cluster.local. udp 101 false 512" NOERROR qr,aa,rd 200 0.000421733s
[INFO] 192.168.2.224:42240 - 22032 "AAAA IN zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-1.zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-headless.idfint.svc.cluster.local. udp 101 false 512" NOERROR qr,aa,rd 194 0.000400037s
[INFO] 192.168.2.224:42240 - 23574 "A IN zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-1.zookafka00-cp-zookeeper-headless.idfint.svc.cluster.local. udp 101 false 512" NOERROR qr,aa,rd 200 0.000458345s
```

**dns service**

```
kubectl get svc --namespace=kube-system
NAME                                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                        AGE
kube-dns                                ClusterIP   10.96.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP         13h
```

```
kubectl get endpoints kube-dns -n kube-system
NAME       ENDPOINTS                                                           AGE
kube-dns   192.168.253.21:53,192.168.94.201:53,192.168.253.21:53 + 3 more...   13h
```

**ping to dns pods**

```
kubectl -n idfint exec -ti dnsutils -- ping  192.168.94.201 -c3
PING 192.168.94.201 (192.168.94.201) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.94.201: icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=0.411 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.94.201: icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=0.344 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.94.201: icmp_seq=3 ttl=62 time=0.405 ms

--- 192.168.94.201 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2034ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.344/0.386/0.411/0.037 ms
❯ kubectl -n idfint exec -ti dnsutils -- ping  192.168.253.21 -c3
PING 192.168.253.21 (192.168.253.21) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.253.21 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2030ms

command terminated with exit code 1
```

**UPDATE**
created a new file `/etc/resolv.conf.1` on each node and reconfigured kubelet to use the flag `--resolv-conf=/etc/resolv.conf.1` as I read ubuntu can create issues with it's resolving service. Did not resolved the issue.

Also any pod un one specific node does not ping any other pod while the pods ping any other pod that stay on any other nodes. Not sure if it's related or not.

I have rebuilt this cluster serveral times always with the same result.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the CNI in used, eg. Flannel?

Comment: What is the node status of your nodes, if so most probably you have not installed a CNI plugin

Comment: Node status is ready. It has calico cni installed.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue, we are currently stuck on same state and tried everything

Comment: No, I droppped the cluster as the networking on the provider side was unreliable.